# Error: Loop must iterate over collection: Boolean

Tags: error, compile-error, loop

I have an issue that I am hoping others may have come across and/or can quickly and easily point out what I have done incorrectly in the below sequence of code.  I am receiving the error Loop must iterate over collection: Boolean on Line 21 for (Case c: Trigger.isUpdate).

In case it is not clear, I just need to grab the AccountId from the Case when updated and input these into custom objects.

I am new to coding and any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```java
trigger CaseAfterUpdate on Case (after update) {

    //Variables
    Set<Id> accountId = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id,Case> allAccIds = new Map<Id, Case>();
    List<MyIns__c> updateIns = new List<MyIns__c>();
    List<MySup__c> updateSup = new List<MySup__c>();
    List<MyIns__c> newIns = new List<MyIns__c>();
    List<MySup__c> newSup = new List<MySup__c>();
    List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();

    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult caseSchema = Schema.SObjectType.Case;
    Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> caseRecordTypeInfo = caseSchema.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
    Id rtCaseDA = caseRecordTypeInfo.get('My_Record_Type').getRecordTypeId();
    system.debug('rtCasefromschema'+rtCaseDA);

    //Id rtCaseDA = [SELECT Id FROM Recordtype WHERE DeveloperName = 'My_Record_Type' AND SObjectType='Case' LIMIT 1].Id ;


    //Update Trigger
    for (Case c: Trigger.isUpdate){

        if (c.RecordTypeId == rtCaseDA && c.Status == 'Approved') {
            //Sup Approved

            accountId.add(c.AccountId);

        }

        allAccIds.put(c.AccountId, c);

    }

    //Ins
    if(allAccIds.size()>0) {

        List <MyIns__c> newIns = [SELECT Id, Id__c, Approved__c FROM MyIns__c WHERE Id__c IN :allAccIds.keyset()];
        for(MyIns__c ins : newIns ) {
            //Update the ins to approved
            for(Case cs : allAccIds.values() ) {
                if(cs.AccountId == ins.Id__c && cs.N_Ins__c == TRUE) {
                    ins.Approved__c = True;
                    updateIns.add(ins);
                }

            }

        }
        if(updateIns.size()>0){
            update updateIns;
        }
    }


    //Sup
    if(allAccIds.size()>0) {

        List <MySup__c> newSup = [SELECT Id, Id__c, Approved__c FROM MySup__c WHERE Id__c IN :allAccIds.keyset()];
        for(MySup__c sup : newSup ) {
            //Update the sup to approved
            for(Case cs : allAccIds.values() ) {
                if(cs.AccountId == sup.Id__c && cs.N_Sup__c == TRUE) {
                    sup.Approved__c = True;
                    updateSup.add(sup);
                }

            }

        }
        if(updateSup.size()>0){
            update updateSup;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have already pointed out the main issue with your code (using `Trigger.isUpdate` instead of `Trigger.new`). The [documentation on Trigger Context Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) is a good reference for the future, as it not only covers *what* each trigger context variable is, but also tells you *when* you can use them (i.e. `Trigger.newMap` is only available `after insert`, both `before update` and `after update`, and `after undelete`).

After improving the formatting of your provided code a bit, there are other concerns that should also be addressed.

Let's work with the following snippet of your code:

```java
if(allAccIds.size()>0) {

    List <MyIns__c> newIns = [SELECT Id, Id__c, Approved__c FROM MyIns__c WHERE Id__c IN :allAccIds.keyset()];
    for(MyIns__c ins : newIns ) {
        //Update the ins to approved
        for(Case cs : allAccIds.values() ) {
            if(cs.AccountId == ins.Id__c && cs.N_Ins__c == TRUE) {
                ins.Approved__c = True;
                updateIns.add(ins);
            }

        }

    }
    if(updateIns.size()>0){
        update updateIns;
    }
}
```

It's good that you keep your query (and DML) outside of all loops (that's a mistake a lot of people new to Apex make, good on you for not falling for that!).

The nested for loop and the `if(recordA.field == recordB.field)` is a red flag. It's not the end of the world, but there is a better way to do this. Use a map. You're actually already most of the way there. Your `allAccIds` variable is a `Map<Id, Case>` where the key of the map is an `AccountId`.

Instead of the second (nested) for loop over the values of `allAccIds`, you can simply pull the exact `Case` record you're looking for using `allAccIds.get(ins.Id__c)`. Using that, your snippet would change to be

```java
if(allAccIds.size()>0) {

    // The Id__c variable is a bit concerning to me.
    // I assume it's a lookup field, in which case a more descriptive field name
    //   that tells you _what_ object it's a lookup to would be more helpful (if
    //   not for you, then for your boss/coworkers/successors).
    // If it's not a lookup field, and just a text field to act as a pseudo-polymorphic
    //   field, having a different name (like Rel_Id__c) would still be helpful.
    // If you were to build a fieldset, or try to include this field on a page layout,
    //   'ID__c' would likely appear as 'Id' or 'ID', very similar to the standard
    //   Id field (making choosing the correct field essentially a coin flip).
    List <MyIns__c> newIns = [SELECT Id, Id__c, Approved__c FROM MyIns__c WHERE Id__c IN :allAccIds.keyset()];
    for(MyIns__c ins : newIns ) {
        //Update the ins to approved

        // Fetching the case from the map is a much better idea than iterating
        //   over your map and trying to manually match cs.AccountId to ins.ID__c.
        // A Map<Id, Case> will only ever associate a particular Id to one Case.
        // If you need to handle instances where an Account can have multiple
        //   Cases related to it, then you'd need a Map<Id, List<Case>>
        Case cs = allAccIds.get(ins.Id__c);

        //if(cs.AccountId == ins.Id__c && cs.N_Ins__c == TRUE) {
        // Fetching a specific value from the map using ins.Id__c means we don't
        //   need to check if cs.AccountId == ins.Id__c anymore.
        // if(var == true) is a bit redundant, and be replaced by if(var)
        if(cs.N_Ins__c){
            ins.Approved__c = True;
            updateIns.add(ins);
        }

    }

    // This check is unnecessary.
    // Salesforce might do some questionable things at times (and they do), but
    //   Apex does have the feature that a DML call on an empty list won't
    //   actually cause triggers to run (it might not even count against your
    //   100 DML call governor limit, though I'm not 100% certain of that)
    //if(updateIns.size()>0){
    update updateIns;
    //}
}
```

One of the things I mentioned deserves more explanation. A `Map<Id, SObject>` will only ever contain one `SObject` (`Case`, in your situation). If you have the following code

```
// Assuming case1 and case2 are previously declared, and are related to the same Account
Map<Id, Case> myMap = new Map<Id,Case>();
map.put(case1.AccountId, case1);
map.put(case2.AccountId, case2);

// This assertion will fail, because when you perform the second put(),
//   the previous value of the map (case1) was overwritten with a new value (case 2)
System.assertEquals(myMap.get(case1.AccountId), case1);
```

Having more than one `Case` related to an `Account` is pretty common (at least it is in my org). If you want to handle that situation, then you need to use a `Map<Id, List<Case>>`, and your code will change again.

```java
// I err on the side of more descriptive variable names.
// This one is a bit on the long side
Map<Id, List<Case>> accountIdsToRelatedCasesMap = new Map<Id, List<Case>>();
for(Case c :Trigger.new){
    // Initializing a collection (map) of collections (lists) requires a bit more consideration
    //   than a collection (map) of single items.
    // There are other ways to do it, but this is my preferred method
    if(!accountIdsToRelatedCasesMap.containsKey(c.AccountId)){
        // In this if statement, we know this is the first time we've encountered
        //   this particular Id.
        // Initialize a new list, and put it in the map for later use.
        accountIdsToRelatedCasesMap.put(c.AccountId, new List<Case>());
    }

    // Outside of the if statement, at this point, we are guaranteed to have something in the map
    //   for the current Case's AccountId, so the following line is safe.
    // <Map var name>.get(<id>) returns a list
    // We can add new items to that list without storing the list in a temporary variable,
    //   and the list stored in the Map is automatically updated.
    accountIdsToRelatedCasesMap.get(c.AccountId).add(c);
}

if(accountIdsToRelatedCasesMap.size()>0) {

    List <MyIns__c> newIns = [SELECT Id, Id__c, Approved__c FROM MyIns__c WHERE Id__c IN :accountIdsToRelatedCasesMap.keyset()];
    for(MyIns__c ins : newIns ) {
        //Update the ins to approved

        // This variable may or may not be required.
        // It'll make more sense in a little bit.
        Boolean allTrue = true;

        // The nested for loop makes a return here, because we do have multiple
        //   cases (potentially, the important thing is that we're working with a List<Case>)
        //   that we need to deal with
        for(Case cs : allAccIds.get(ins.Id__c) ) {
            //if(cs.AccountId == ins.Id__c && cs.N_Ins__c == TRUE) {
            // By building our Map<Id, List<Case>>, we ensured that every Case
            //   in the list for a particular Account Id is related to that Account.
            // That means that the check for cs.AccountId == ins.Id__c is still not required
            if(cs.N_Ins__c){
                ins.Approved__c = True;
                updateIns.add(ins);

                // In this situation, it may be possible that more than one Case
                //   will have N_Ins__c ==  true.
                // Adding the same record to a list more than once will cause
                //   issues when you perform DML on that list.
                // To avoid that, you need to decide what should happen when
                //   you have multiple cases that might not agree with each other.
                // Specifically, does a single true value of N_Ins__c mean you
                //   want to approve the MyIns__c record, or do all of your cases
                //   need to have N_Ins__c == true?

                // In the case where a single true is enough, we want to 'break'
                //   the inner loop so we guarantee that we don't add the current
                //   MyIns__c record to the update list a second time.
                break;
            }

            // In the case where all related Cases need to be true, a single false
            //   is enough to tell us that we can stop work for this MyIns__c record
            // This code is commented out because the two different situations
            // (one cs.N_Ins__c is true vs all are true) are  mutually exclusive
            // You need to choose which one of these strategies you want to use,
            //   and only use the code for that strategy.
            //if(!cs.N_Ins__c){
            //    allTrue = false;
            //    break;
            //}

        }

        // The final part of the "all cases must be true" path.
        // Since we need to check all of the cases to determine whether or not
        //   to execute this code, it needs to be outside of the loop over cases.
        //if(allTrue){
        //    ins.Approved__c = true;
        //    updateIns.add(ins);
        //}

    }

    // This check is unnecessary.
    // Salesforce might do some questionable things at times (and they do), but
    //   Apex does have the feature that a DML call on an empty list won't
    //   actually cause triggers to run (it might not even count against your
    //   100 DML call governor limit, though I'm not 100% certain of that)
    //if(updateIns.size()>0){
    update updateIns;
    //}
}
```

Comment: Derek - since you've gone all in here with an excellent tutorial, you might as well point out that the last if statement: `if(updateIns.size()>0)` is unnecessary and OP can just use `update updateIns;` - if list is empty SFDC does nothing.

Comment: @cropredy right, missed that one. Updating now.

Comment: Hi Derek, using your code is fine, until I tried this against a Custom Setting, without luck.  Should this work?

Comment: @Stuart I can't say too much given so little information. The general ideas I presented should work fine, though there will likely be differences in the actual code if Custom Settings are involved. At any rate, it sounds like something you should ask a new question for.

Answer (score 4):

The error is here:

```
for (Case c: Trigger.isUpdate){  // This is line 21
```

You most likely meant to iterate over Trigger.new:

```
for (Case c: Trigger.new){
```

Which is a list that contains the cases which are being updated.

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over a boolean variable at this line.

```
for (Case c: Trigger.isUpdate)
```

`Trigger.isUpdate` will return either true or false. This is used to identify if an update operation is being carried out.

We run a for loop on a `collection` type, viz. **list, set and maps**. Here instead of `Trigger.isUpdate`, you either need to iterate over the context variable `Trigger.new`(if you want to refer new values) or `Trigger.old`(if you want to refer old values)

So the code should be like this:

```
for (Case c: Trigger.new)
```

or

```
for (Case c: Trigger.old)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please exchange `Trigger.isUpdate` to `Trigger.New`

1-`Trigger.isUpdate` is a condition to check record is update or not.

2- You want to iterate so you can use `Trigger.New`

Answer (score 1):

Trigger.isupdate is a bollean variable, either it will return true or false.
You have to use Trigger.New to get list newly inserted or updated records.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to complete a very similar update (just using different fields), but instead of a custom object update a custom setting, what changes would I need to make to the code provided?  I have tried the same method, but it does not seem to update the record.

```
if(accountIdsToRelatedCasesMap.size()>0) {

List <MyCustomSetting__c> newCS = [SELECT Id, Field1__c, Field2__c FROM MyCustomSetting__c WHERE Field1__c IN :accountIdsToRelatedCasesMap.keyset()];
for(MyCustomSetting__c cs : newCS ) {
    Boolean allTrue = true;

    for(Case c : allAccIds.get(cs.Field1__c) ) {
        if(c.N_Ins__c){
            cs.Approved__c = True;
            updateCS.add(cs);

            break;
        }

    }

}

update updateCS;
```

}